# Use a function in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How to use a function in a ng-repeat values? For example, I have a date from order I have to calcculate a date diff so I need something like this: `getDateDiffInDays({{order.dateOrder}})`:

**View:**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-controller="Orders" ng-repeat="order in orders">
        {{order.product}} | {{order.dateOrder}} | getDateDiffInDays({{order.dateOrder}});
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```js
.controller('Orders',function($scope){
    $scope.today = new Date();
    this.getDateDiffInDays = function(dateParam) { //dateParam is a timestamp
        var t1 = today.getTime();
        return parseInt((t1-dateParam)/(24*3600*1000));
    }
}]);
```

Any Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response from CD.. is correct but a filter seems appropriate for your use case:

Your html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-controller="Orders" ng-repeat="order in orders">
        {{order.product}} | {{order.dateOrder | getDateDiffInDays}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Your application:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('getDateDiffInDays', function() {
    return function(myDate) {
        var t1 = new Date().getTime();
        return parseInt((t1 - myDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000), 10);
    };
});

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.orders = [
        { product: 'foo', dateOrder: new Date(2014, 0, 1) },
        { product: 'bar', dateOrder: new Date(2013, 0, 1) }
    ];
}]);
```

It is easy because you make a diff with current date, but if you need more complex diff, you can give parameter to your filter:

Your html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-controller="Orders" ng-repeat="order in orders">
        {{order.product}} | {{order.dateOrder | getDateDiffInDays:today}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Your application:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('getDateDiffInDays', function() {
    return function(myDate, baseDate) {
        // Second parameter can be optional
        var t1 = (baseDate || new Date()).getTime();
        return parseInt((t1 - myDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000), 10);
    };
});

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
    $scope.orders = [
        { product: 'foo', dateOrder: new Date(2014, 0, 1) },
        { product: 'bar', dateOrder: new Date(2013, 0, 1) }
    ];
}]);
```

Now you have a reusable filter.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n78k9/2

Answer (score 1):

As @Mickael solution would be the right angular way, you can add your function to the scope,

Like:

```
$scope.getDateDiffInDays = function() { . . . }
```

and in your view call it like:

```
{{ getDateDiffInDays(order.dateOrder) }}
```